# What is the camera preview ratio in iPhone X?

Tags: swift, camera

I try to show preview camera in center of my view, but there is a black bottom.
the ratio of preview if 4/3.
this code works fine on all device except iPhoneX.
unfortunately I can not debug on iPhoneX( I have an iPhone 7).
on iPhoneX the Preview is translated on wrong position ( right, bottom corner)

```
 if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera){
       //camera not available
       return
    }

    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
    imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.view.frame = cameraViewContainer.bounds

    //center screen camera preview
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size

    let cameraAspectRatio : CGFloat = 4.0 / 3.0

    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait  {
        let cameraImageHeight = screenSize.width * cameraAspectRatio
        imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: (screenSize.height - cameraImageHeight) / 2 )

    }
   else  if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
         let cameraImageWidth = screenSize.height * cameraAspectRatio
         imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: (screenSize.width - cameraImageWidth) / 2 )

    }

    cameraViewContainer.addSubview( imagePicker.view )
```

Answer (score 0):

Googling the aspect ratio of the camera and setting it in code didn't help, what I did that helped in a way was to set cameraViewContainer as an outlet in my storyboard and set it's constraints to have it centered in the screen, that way the issue in the iphone X was solved.

Comment: cameraViewContainer is already centered by constraint in storyboard.
the UIView imagePicker.view is correctly centered but the preview camera( inside   imagePicker.view) has a bottom black border ( preview is not in full screen) .
the Height is calculated by apply the ratio ( width * 4 /3 ).
its work on iPhone 7,6,SE but not in iPhoneX.
the preview size in iphone7 is 375X500 DO you know the preview size on iPhoneX ?

Comment: this is what I am looking for. Do you know the preview size of the iPhone X and larger ones?

Comment: @adri657 this may help with that https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions